# Images being uploaded multiple times instead of once

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been using the library of Multi Image Picker of flutter(https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/multi_image_picker).Recently , i have an issue with image upload.
The issue is that when i check the logs , the image is being uploaded multiple times .
I want to upload a particular image once .

```
void _loadImage() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(SAMPLE URL);
  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
  request.headers['authorization'] = getAccessToken(prefs);
  ByteData byteData = await this._asset.requestOriginal();
  List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

  var multipartfile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    'image',
    imageData,
    filename: 'image.jpg',
    contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg"),
  );
  request.files.add(multipartfile);
  var response = await request.send();
  String responseData = await response.stream
      .transform(utf8.decoder)
      .join(); // decodes on response data using UTF8.decoder
  //print(responseData);
  Map data = (json.decode(responseData)); // Parse data from JSON string
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    await finalData.add(data);
  }
  print(finalData);
  this._asset.releaseOriginal();
  print(response.statusCode);
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    print("Error Uploading");
  } else {
    await this._asset.requestThumbnail(300, 300, quality: 50);
  }

  if (this.mounted) {
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `this.mounted` doing and where do you call `_loadImage()` ?

Comment: please show how are you calling `_loadImage()`